# Неверные данные в localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage, fetch

У меня есть файл с авторизацией пользователя, при логине я получаю токен в localStorage. С этим все в порядке.

```
import saveToken from '../token';
import performRequest from '../requests';

export default function loginRequest(email, password) {
  return performRequest(`/api/login?password=${password}&userName=${email}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then(saveToken);
}
```

Но когда я регистрирую нового пользователя, то вместо токена в `tokenData` сохраняется `"{\"id\":60}"` (цифра не обязательно такая, она меняется после каждой регистрации)

```
sendIdRequest(id, email, password) {
    return performRequest(`/api/users/${id}/creds`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          password: password,
          userName: email,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then(saveToken)
  }
```

Сам `saveToken`

```
export default function saveToken(token) {
  localStorage.setItem('tokenData', JSON.stringify(token));
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после регистрации в localStorage сохранялся сам токен, оценю любую вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, вам по-разному приходят данные с сервера при логине и регистрации - в первом случае только число, во втором - объект с полем id. Для сохранения токена после регистрации нужна функция типа такой:

```
function saveRegistrationToken(token) {
  localStorage.setItem('tokenData', JSON.parse(token).id);
}
```

В вашей фукнции `saveToken` используется `JSON.stringify`, (а не `JSON.parse`) поэтому получается неожиданный результат.

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ, в данный момент вместо токена заносится просто id, только не так, как раньше, а просто число, допустим 2

Comment: А в каком виде до этого сохранялся сохранялся токен?